# Change Office 2016 setup log directory to custom location

Tags: installation, microsoft-office, logging, command-line-arguments, microsoft-office-2016

I can't seem to figure out how to change the default Office setup.exe log location from C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\SetupExe(blablabalbaba).log to somewhere else locally on the disk. This article is of no use and the arguments listed do not work.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/826511/how-to-use-a-setup-log-to-troubleshoot-setup-problems-in-office

If you pass /L and a file path, it doesn't recognize the /L parameter. Same with /L*v. I also can't find anywhere in the ODT to be able to change the installer log path.

I am using an MSP file for customization via the /adminfile command. I don't think I can use a config.xml file in tandem and I don't think that's necessary if I already have an MSP file.

I don't even need a verbose log, I just want to change where it's putting the installer log by default. This should be very simple like most MSI installers allow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using volume licensed MSI version of Office 2016, we can specify the setup log location by using the Logging Path parameter in config.xml file.

```
<Logging Type="standard" Path="%temp%" Template="Microsoft Office Professional Plus Setup(*).txt" />
```

Change the Path to your wanted location. More information about the config.xml file, read https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-2013-resource-kit/cc179195(v=office.15)#logging-element

Comment: I was under the impression that you cannot use a config file and MSP in tandem. Is this not the case?